# Compare Dataframe values and change column if match is found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I am trying to achieve is having two dataframes that contatains IP Addresses and Dns values. My goal is to loop through the scanner_df ips and match them with the edr_dr. If a match of the Ips is found the scanner df Dns name is empty then append to the scanner df the value that the edr_df has.

basically loop through the scanner_df and if a NaN value is found On the DNS column then replace it with the DNS values of the edr_df that corresponds to the same ip

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

dict1 = {
    "Scanner IP": ["10.10.230.51","10.10.230.56","10.10.230.55","10.10.230.53", "10.10.230.112","10.10.230.146"],
    "DNS Name":["domain.comany.com","nan","domain122.comany.com","nan","something.com", "this.com"]
}

dict2 ={
    "EDR IP":["10.10.230.51","10.10.230.56","10.10.230.55","10.10.230.53"],
    "DNS Name":["domain.comany.com","anotherdomain.company.com","domain122.comany.com","adfadf.comany.com"]
}

edr_df = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

scanner_df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

for scanner_ip in scanner_df.values:
    for edr_ip in edr_df.values:
        if str(scanner_ip[0]) == str(edr_ip[0]):
            if str(scanner_ip[1]) == 'nan':
                # command to update the scanner_df empty DNS values
```

[image: Example]

Comment: The question is unclear, but it's either a `groupby.ffill`/`bfill` or a `merge`/`map`. Make sure to use real NaNs (not strings).

Comment: basically loop through the scanner_df and if a NaN value is found On the DNS collumn then replace it with the DNS values of the edr_df that corresponds to the same ip

Comment: @mozway its is not duplicate with what you linked. The linked questions just fill values with the last one. I do not want that

Comment: @mozway also it is not merging. I want to update not merge

Comment: Then please provide your input as `DataFrame` constructor and the matching expected output in the same format, I'll be happy to give you the command (or reopen if this was not a duplicate). NB. `merge`/`map` **can** be used to update.

Comment: Offcourse I cannot provide the real data given that it is sensitive. But I can provide some dummy data

Comment: Dummy data is better, keep it short but meaningful.

Comment: I have added some dummy data

Comment: OK, then as I said, it's a `map`: `m = scanner_df['DNS Name'].eq('nan') ; scanner_df.loc[m, 'DNS Name'] = scanner_df.loc[m, 'Scanner IP'].map(edr_df.set_index('EDR IP')['DNS Name'])`

Comment: this has not work on the ACTUAL data. Throws pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. Any idea what that might be?

Comment: Do you have duplicates? If yes, you need to drop them.